# flutter & firebase: writing successfully with error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have some seemingly very strange behavior. I've been following multiple tutorials on integrating firebase into my flutter app.

I'm trying to do something very simple. When the user presses a button, a "session" document is created.

I have this `index.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addSession = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const sessions = admin.firestore().collection('sessions');
    return sessions.add({
        game: data['game'],
        rules: data['rules'],
        password: data['password'],
        roomCode: data['roomCode'],
        playerIds: data['playerIds']
    });
});
```

When invoked in Flutter, the data is successfully written to the database (I can see it in the console), but I also always get this error:
`[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Firebase function failed with exception., {message: INTERNAL, code: INTERNAL})`

When I check the Firebase logs, I see this:
[image]

Flutter invocation:

```
final HttpsCallable callable =
        CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'addSession');
    await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'game': game,
      'rules': 'default',
      'password': password,
      'roomCode': _roomCode,
      'playerIds': [123456],
    });
```

Very confused about this, nothing about `maximum stack call size exceeded` results seem to be relevant. This is very simple code!

Also wondering if this has anything to with reading issues I am having, which I will ask in a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what you're returning from the function.  Callable functions will generate a response to the client based on what the code returns.  That response will be serialized to JSON.  Your code returns a promise that resolves with a DocumentReference, and that DocumentReference doesn't serialize very well because it contains circular references.

What you should do instead is return something explicit and simple to the client.  For example:

```
exports.addSession = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const sessions = admin.firestore().collection('sessions');
    await sessions.add({
        game: data['game'],
        rules: data['rules'],
        password: data['password'],
        roomCode: data['roomCode'],
        playerIds: data['playerIds']
    });
    return { result: "OK" }
});
```

You can return whatever you find more helpful, of course.  Note that I'm using async/await synctax in JavaScript to make it easier. Promises work like Futures in dart.

Comment: thanks very much! that worked (once I removed the `await`, it was causing a warning for linting)

Comment: I would not expect the function to work 100% of the time without await.  `add()` is asynchronous and needs time to complete before the function can return its response.  The promise it returns must be resolved before the response can be returned.

Comment: i will look into this! thanks again. by any chance could you take a look at another question i have? i feel like it's a minimal example that isn't working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922315/flutter-firebase-unable-to-read?noredirect=1#comment109522734_61922315